# Morris.js chart shows up below container

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, morris.js

I'm using a rails app, and following the Morris.js Railscast.

I can't figure out this strange CSS bug.  Help??
I've tried it with or without float, same thing happens.

The site is http://theactiongame.com

My code is at http://github.com/bluemihai/the-action-game

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this will help but have you tried wrapping it with $(document).ready() ?

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: also adding a direct link to the line of source code on GitHub would help you get better answers.  No one has time to click around in your source to find the reference...